# What is OWID_WRL in Datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-analysis, data-cleaning

Help me with this,
OWID_WRL Column in the dataset, what is it, how should it be categorized in the dataset, which country is it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lThr.png)

Comment: please take a look on how to write a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also consider adding the data directly on the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Our World in Data dataset downloads in CSV format have such information, for example in [Deaths by age, World, 1990 to 2017](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/number-of-deaths-by-age-group) we can see those values.

Answer (score 0):

I think OWID_WRL refers to the world. I ran into the same question and found some information on this page.

'On 25 April 2020, we added rows for "World" and "International" to our complete dataset. The iso_code column for "International" is blank, and for "World" we use OWID_WRL.'

https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/README.md